# datasnap client in c#

Tags: c#, delphi, datasnap

how to create a datasnap client in c# with visual studio 2008 (or 2010)?

datasnap has  ado.net provider(C#) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are videos and tutorials in internet,

> http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jimtierney/2009/03/25/31442

I think you need delphi prism

Comment: Page not found. :|

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Delphi Prism - I've described that in my Delphi 2010 DataSnap white paper (not in the Delphi XE edition of the DataSnap white paper), and also in my Delphi XE DAtaSnap XE courseware manual (available on Lulu.com or from my own bookshop).

I've never tried to write the client in C# instead of Delphi Prism. You do need some assemblies that are part of Delphi Prism, so even if you want to write a pure C# client, you will probably need some Delphi Prism.

Unless you expose the DataSnap Server methods using REST, in which case you can just call them using C# or any language of course.

What is it exactly that you are looking for to connect to?

Comment: How about DS in XE5 and Prism XE3 on Studio 2010? Will it work? I think Oxygene for .Net is not free now? How about XE5/6 owners?